# Present Perfect for dead person

Tags: present-perfect

Can we use 'Before she died, she has won several awards'? We  know that she died and she had won awards and she has been given several awards since she died.(still taking )

Comment: No, dead people are not in the present, grammatically speaking. Therefore I would not even say: *After she died, she has won several awards posthumously.* I would put even that sentence in the past tense.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can not use a present tense before a past tense. In your case better fits past perfect which expresses a past finished event before another finished event in the past:

> Before she died, she had won several awards.

EDIT:

Or, the simple past which expresses a finished event in the past can be used as well:

> Before she died, she won several awards.

Answer (score 0):

When you use 'before' **here**, you use the past perfect - 'had won'. It is `had+past participle`. Why? Because in such context, the thing has happened in the past **before** something that is already in past.

---

However, I see no need of using 'before' in that sentence. "She had won several awards during her lifetime." is what ***I*** may prefer.